# Adding Foreign keys from multiple tables, how to ensure sequence

Tags: database, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So this is basically my current task.

2 Tables have received a certain number of auto-generated data.

```
Table_1 id number, identitynumber number, name varchar2, sex varchar2, birthday date;

Table_2 id number, identification number, manufacturer varchar2, typ varchar2;
```

The ID values on both tables are the primary keys of each table. Now I gotta insert the data from these 2 tables into a 3rd table, that'll use these ids as foreign keys. This table should also receive some auto-generated data.

```
Table_3 id number, plate varchar2, id_table1 number, id_table2 number, from date, until date;
```

I planned on using a insert with a select to query the required data:

```
insert into table_3 (id, plate, id_table1, id_table2, from, until)
   select function_randomID as id,
      generate_randomPlate as plate,
      (select t1.id
      from table_1) as id_table1,
      (select t2.od
      from table_2) as id_table2,
      generate_date as from,
      gemerate_date as until
   from dual;
```

Now, I know the selects for both IDs are incorrect, and this is precisely the question.

***I don't know what condition I need to put into those selects, in order to get a single row and add that into the third table.***

Sorry if I didn't ask it in a more succinct way. Hopefully it's clear enough now to be understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I gotta insert the data from these 2 tables into a 3rd table,
>   that'll use these ids as foreign keys. This table should also receive
>   some auto-generated data.

Assuming you autogenerated number are coming from a `function`, you can try this:

```
INSERT INTO table_3 (id,
                     plate,
                     id_table1,
                     id_table2,
                     fm,--From is a reserve keyword
                     until)
   SELECT function_randomID AS id,
          generate_randomPlate AS plate,
          tb1.id,
          tb2.id,
          generate_date AS fm,
          gemerate_date AS untl
     FROM table_1 tb1 
    CROSS JOIN table_2 tb2 ;
   --ON tb1.id = tb2.id;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that detail, while "id" is named the same on both table_1 and table_2, they are also randomly generated, and have no correlation. If I try using an inner join with them and comparing their values, it might happen that they never even match, since they're both randomly generated from a huge number interval.

Comment: @AWildmann Then replace the inner join with a cross join . See my updated answer. So now the result wil be a cartesin product of both the tables.

Comment: I managed to get somewhat forward with the task with the help, thanks!